# Pros and cons of window.postMessage vs ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I recently learned about the HTML 5 API of window.parent.postMessage, and was wondering what are the pros and cons of using that vs a simply ajax call,

For example, creating a listener of a message event on the client side for e.origin==='www.example.com', and on www.example.com, sending an a page containing

```
window.parent.postMessage(data,'*');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use cases for AJAX and Window.postMessage() are different.

With AJAX you send a message from the browser to the server. It is picked op and processed by a script running on the server (written for PHP, Node.js, Ruby, Python, Java, etc.), which sends a response back to the browser.

Window.postMessage() will send a message from one browser window to another, for instance from an iframe to it's parent window. The data is never send to the server.

Comment: Can you qualify `The data is never send to the server.`? I would like to validate an access token sent via postMessage because I cannot trust the origin.

Comment: i know this is kinda old, but there is nothing to qualify. window.postmessage posts a message to the browser window. Typically this is done to send a message to/from an iframe.
This only ever enters the front end. Unless you utilize that data in a way that then sends it to the server (capturing it in an iframe for an ajax post) it never actually goes to the server. It remains in the front end.

Comment: This is false. iFrames can be used to communicate on server-level and have been used for that purpose even before AJAX came upon. iFrames can be targetted by forms which would reload the iFrame and post the message server-side. The addition of postMessage only improved that so that the iFrame can explicitly communicate with the parent window, even if it is cross-origin. To boot, parent-to-iFrame postMessage can also reload the iFrame to send data server-side, or use form-target in combination. iFrame.postMessage is better than AJAX for having no cross-origin limitation to send/receive data.